# rails_autolink gem for my comments issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to implement this option: On my app, users can create posts and comment on posts as well. If a user wants to show a URL in either the `www` format or `http` format, how should I display that using the `rails_autolink` gem? I want the url to be clickable and take you to the link. I have already installed the gem and I added it to my posts controller. Another user suggested that gem to me but I do not understand how to implement it. Users create comments from the posts show template. Does the gem need to be used in the `show template` or the `posts_controller`?

this is my post `show.html.erb`:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h2>
    <%= @post.title %>
    <small>
      posted by <%= link_to @post.creator.username %> <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) + ' ago' %>
      | <%= link_to 'go to link', fix_url(@post.url) %>
      <% if logged_in? && (@post.creator == current_user) %> |
        <%= link_to 'edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
        <i class="icon-user icon"></i>
      <% end %>
    </small>
  </h2>
</div>

<h3><%= @post.description %></h3>
  <%= render 'shared_partials/errors', errors_obj: @comment %>

  <%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, :class=> "span4", :placeholder=> "Comment goes here", :rows => "7" %>
    </br>
    <div class="button">
    <%= f.submit "Create a comment", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="page-header">
  <h4>All Comments</h4>
</div>
<% @post.newest_comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div class="comments">
    <h5><%= comment.body %></h5>
      <li>
       <small class="muted">
        posted by <%= link_to comment.creator.username %> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) + ' ago' %>
        <% if logged_in? && (comment.creator == current_user) %> |
          <%= link_to 'edit', edit_post_comment_path(@post, comment) %> |
          <i class="icon-user icon"></i>
        <% end %>
      </small>
      </li>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and my posts_controller:

```
require 'rails_autolink'
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :vote]
  before_action :require_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :vote]
  before_action :require_creator, only:[:edit, :update]

  def index
    @posts = Post.page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').per_page(15)
  end

  def show
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.creator = current_user

    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "You created a post!"
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "You updated the post!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def vote
    Vote.create(voteable: @post, creator: current_user, vote: params[:vote])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :vote } # Renders views/posts/vote.js.erb
    end
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:url, :title, :description)
  end

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def require_creator
    access_denied if @post.creator != current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that `rails_autolink` will do what you're looking to accomplish. Basically, [per the documentation](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink), the gem interpolates URLs in outputted text to a hyperlink that encloses the URL as text. By default, markup is outputted as sanitized `html_safe` strings:

```
auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org and say hello")
# => "Go to <a href=\"http://www.rubyonrails.org\">http://www.rubyonrails.org</a> and say hello"
```

You should be using it directly in your view/template and you *should not* need to require it in our controller. Rails typically requires gem dependencies at application load, so you don't need to include them at runtime.